# Displaying an array with a tree structure and each of it's preceding branches

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with unlimited children on each of the elements. For example each of the children can have it's own children.
Right now I am checking each of the elements for children and doing a foreach on them, but I would like to use a recursive function for it.
The problem I am facing is, how to print all of the preceding branches at each of the tree levels.

My array structure looks like this :

```
   [ 0 : {
           Name : Animals,
           Children : [
             0 : { Name : Dogs,
                   Children : [
                      0 : { Name : Retrievers,
                            Children : [ 
                                0 : { Name : Golden Retriever , 
                                      Children : [] 
                                     }
                                 ]
                   ] 
                  }
               ]
         }
   ]
```

I cannot know how many levels the tree will have.

What I am trying to achieve is a display as this :

Animals

Animals > Dogs

Animals > Dogs > Retrievers

Animals > Dogs > Retrievers > Golden Retriever

An example of what I am trying to achieve can be found here https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/verticals

Does anyone have any idea of where to start or having a faced a similar problem? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($tree));

$names = [];
foreach ($iterator as $name) {
    // As depth will be increasing by 2, starting from 1,
    // we need to devide in half and floor. This way our $names array
    // will have normal sequantial indexes.
    $depth = floor($iterator->getDepth() / 2);

    $names[$depth] = $name;

    echo implode(' > ', array_slice($names, 0, $depth + 1)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/099a266766795e7db04830fadf68514d1cc8e7cd).